# Complex Python dictionary item retrieval/ printing

Tags: python, json, parsing, dictionary

I find myself in python dictionary (json) hell. Please see the json code I mocked-up below that mimics a snip of my real data. I understand how to use Python to get the values associated with the `Key1e` and `Key2e` via `jsondata['Dict1]['Dict1a']['Key2'][0]['Key1a'][0]['Key1b']['Key12c']`. But now I want to print these values every time they appear. **Edit** I'm using the json module.

**Edit: I've tried:**

`activity = jsondata['Dict1']['Dict1a']['Key2'][0]['Key1a']`

...then I want to iterate over the 15 items within it to print, so I tried:

```
for i in activity:
    print ['Key1b']['Key12c'] #to actually retrieve what's in `Key12c`
```

I also tried:

```
holder = []
for i in activity:
    holder.append(['Key1b']['Key12c'])
```

...to no avail (same error of course)

But the above produces a "list indices must be integers, not str" error. Should I be attempting to get the index values?

I also included a screenshot of the JSON structure revealed when I pasted my code into an online JSON viewer.

```
{"Dict1":{"Dict1a":{"Key1":"Value1","Key2":[{"Key1a":[{"Key1b":
{"Key1c":"Value1c","Key2c":"Value2c","Key3c":{"Key1d":"Value1d","Key2d":"Value2d"},
"Key4c":"Value4c","Key5c":"Value5c","Key6c":"Value6c","Key7c":"Value7c",
"Key8c":"Value8c","Key9c":"Value9c","Key10c":[],"Key11c":"Value11c",
"Key12c":{"Key1e": 1234,"Key2e": 5378}}}]}]}}}
```

**Another edit:** Please note that the `0` under the `Key1a` refers to one of 15, but that's not represented in the JSON view below. It's these 15 items I'd like to iterate over.

[image: This is the JSON structure (I pasted the above code into an online json viewer)]

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service - what have you *actually tried*, and what is the problem with it?

Comment: Are you using the `json` module?

Comment: python json module, isinstance function and a recursive function are the keys. Try and let people see what you have done by editing your question.

Comment: Every time I'm confronted with a horrible nested `json` blob I'm tempted to convert it to `XML` and then use [tag:xpath] to query for what I need. It hasn't quite come to it yet, but there have been some close calls.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. For loop was incorrect. 
Should have been:

```
for i in activity:
   print i['Key1b']['Key12c']
```